# C++ code fails to compile with error 'long type-name' is invalid

Tags: c++, c++14, thrift

I prefer to avoid using `typedef` preferring `using` instead but I have stumbled across the situation where I have to use it since the code outputted by `thrift` (version 0.9.3) uses a `typedef`.  The smallest instance of the error comes in the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef int64_t long;
typedef int32_t int;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello world " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error I get is

```
test.cpp:4:17: error: 'long type-name' is invalid
typedef int64_t long;
                ^
test.cpp:4:1: error: typedef requires a name [-Werror,-Wmissing-declarations]
typedef int64_t long;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:5:17: error: cannot combine with previous 'type-name' declaration specifier
typedef int32_t int;
                ^
test.cpp:5:1: error: typedef requires a name [-Werror,-Wmissing-declarations]
typedef int32_t int;
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
4 errors generated.
```

The output I get from `g++ --version` is

```
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Could someone help with this error?

Comment: Can you post your thrift file as well?

Comment: Thrift doesn't come up with this all by itself, you need to feed it something.

Answer (score 2):

`long` is a keyword in c++, so you cannot create a type with name `long`. See the [list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword).

But the question is with Thrift generated code. I did some experiments with Thrift, and I can reproduce the problem by adding this line to the official `tutorial.thrift` file:

```
typedef i64 long
```

Apparently Thrift won't check whether this is going to compile or not. So you need to make sure your typedef is ok with all possible languages.

Comment: I don't think its a problem with me understanding why the error is there.  Sorry if I worded this wrong,  I was trying to understand why thrift is creating that error in the C++ code..

Comment: I see. However, IMHO, it's not likely to be a problem with Thrift. That's why I am asking for your thrift file.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
typedef long int64_t;
typedef int int32_t;
```

Typedefs work like variable declarations, just with `typedef` in front.

Comment: @Curious How are you calling thrift?

Comment: `thrift --gen cpp test.thrift`

Comment: @Curious What's in `test.thrift`?